# Discord bot returns empty string instead

Tags: javascript, proxy, discord, discord.js

So my bot basically generates and checks if a proxy works on a selected site (i.e supremenewyork.com)
However. It returns an empty string. I feel like its my Proxy API,  but it seems to be working fine once tested. Any help is appreciated. 
Everything else works the command itself works.

Here's a throwbin of the code:
https://throwbin.io/XNFiJKP

This is what it returns

```
Supreme: INVALID

Nike: INVALID

Undefeated: INVALID

Kith: INVALID

YeezySupply: INVALID
```

Comment: You should include the code with an explanation here

Comment: What line is returning the empty string?

Comment: You should always include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the post, not as an external link. Not only would this help us find the issue, but often it helps you find the issue before even posting.

Comment: it returns this: Free Proxy: 

Supreme: INVALID

Nike: INVALID

Undefeated: INVALID

Kith: INVALID

YeezySupply: INVALID